# Mapbox and leaflet for custom centering

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Im sorry if this question is for dummies.

I'm using mapbox on a web development and I have "side" panels next to my map.

The thing is that I want to center the map on a location that I capture by double clicking it.

I know that `map.setView([lat,lng],number)` or `map.panTo([lat,lng])` do the centering  magic, but they do it over the actual size of the map o div width.

I want to know if anyone knows if I can do a custom  centering, like using the same map size but the center "calculation" occurs on the left or right half of the map.

I dont know how to catch this "resolution" all I know is that I need the half of the width that the map uses. Here is an image of what I want to do [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1dhM.png)

Answer (score 1):

(probably a duplicate question with that one on GIS StackExchange: [Change the center point of leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170702/change-the-center-point-of-leaflet))

You will probably be interested in one of those plugins:

- [Leaflet-active-area](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area)

  > This plugin allows you to use a smaller portion of the map as an active area. All positioning methods (setView, fitBounds, setZoom) will be applied on this portion instead of the all map.
- [Leaflet.ControlledBounds](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.ControlledBounds)

  > Inspired by Leaflet-active-area, automatically detects the largest area of the map not covered by any map controls and applies setView, fitBounds, setZoom, getBounds to that area.

Comment: thank you, i was reading the active area but what I understood was that if I use it, the set view will change permanently. I dont want to use the active area all the time, only when the user do an specific event.

Am I wrong? thx for the help

Comment: When the event that changes the "active area" triggers, I think you just need to call again `map.setActiveArea({ /* styles */ })`, probably with a `map.getBounds()` before and `map.fitBounds()` after.

Answer (score 0):

finally I figured out how to center the `panTo()` the way i wanted.

i used this
 `myLayer.on('click',function(e){
                    var vista=$('#map').width()/4; 
                    map.setView(new L.LatLng(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng),15);
                    map.panBy([-vista,0]);}`