# Offsett the center of leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I have different text boxes in a scrollable overlay that triggers flyto() on different places on the map. Now each popup appears in the center of the div holding the map and gets covered by the overlay.

[image: "I have narrow space so need the popup to the right and then place the infobox to the left"]

How can I offsett where the popup are shown?

Ive tried this:

```
 const createMap = () => {
    map = L.map('newmap', { zoomControl: false }).setView(mapData[0].coordinates, 7)
    ...
    .addTo(map)
   const offset = map.getSize().x * 0.4
    map.panBy(new L.Point(-offset, 0), { animate: false })
  }
```

But the map centeres itself when this function runs:

```
    const markAndFly = () => {
        currentItem.subscribe((newIndex) => {
          //removes previous marker if value is set
          if (marker !== null) {
            map.removeLayer(marker)
          }
          const place = mapData[newIndex].coordinates
          //adding marker to a first, and then new layer
          marker = new L.marker(place, { icon: L.divIcon($useIcon) })
          map.addLayer(marker)
          //moves the map to the next place
          map.flyTo(place, 7, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 1.5,
          })
   }
  }
```

Ive tried including the offset-part to this last function, but the map still centers.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944128/mapbox-and-leaflet-for-custom-centering/33954790#33954790

Comment: I want to achieve this without a plug-in. Already seen those post.